# Replace '.00' to blank value in xml with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a xml file with tag .
However, the value in the tag somehow displayed as 111.01.00 then i want to remove .00.
I've tried to replace function but it seems to print to powershell screen instead of saving though i already had save function
Here is my code:

```
param ($folder = 'C:\Users\blitz\Desktop\Baiduri\CR\new_xml_format')
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Include "*xml" -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file
$xml.SelectNodes('//*[self::balance]') |
    ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' -replace '.00',''} 
$xml.Save($file)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're replacing the text but you're not actually doing anything with it. Set the item back with the results.

```
param ($folder = 'C:\Users\blitz\Desktop\Baiduri\CR\new_xml_format')
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Include "*xml" -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file
$xml.SelectNodes('//*[self::balance]') |
    ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' = $_.'#text' -replace '.00',''} 
$xml.Save($file)
}
```

When you're replacing something with nothing you can omit the `,''` and make it just

```
$_.'#text' = $_.'#text' -replace '.00'
```

Comment: Btw Im using the same way to replace empty node with 0 but it doesn't work.
    ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' = $_.'#text' -replace '`0','0'} 
Can you to help correct...

Comment: What's with the ` in front of the 0?

Comment: As my understanding. 0 mean breakline.

Comment: My node like <balance/><balance>, then i want to change to <balance/>0<balance>

Answer (score 1):

Actually, @DougMaurer is ok but we don't need Regex here though, `-replace` uses Regex and . Bears meaningful to Regex (Match any character). Then change it to:

```
$_.'#text'.replace(".00","")
```